# Adding Editable Fields in Adobe Echo Sign Widget

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Adobe Echo Sign API createwidget for signing documents,I want to add editable fields, Like we get when we select "Preview, position signatures or add form fields"  [here](https://secure.echosign.com/public/compose), I have attached the screen shot as well [image: Fields]
I have tried using MergeField Info of createwidget but its not creating fields on widget [API documentation](https://secure.echosign.com/public/docs/EchoSignDocumentService16#WidgetCreationInfo)

Here's my code

WidgetCreationInfo widgetinfo = new WidgetCreationInfo(widgetname, fileInfos);

```
MergeField[] mergedfields = new MergeField[1];
mergedfields[0] = new MergeField();
mergedfields[0].fieldName = "name";
mergedfields[0].defaultValue = "Salman";

MergeFieldInfo mergedfieldinfo = new MergeFieldInfo();
mergedfieldinfo.mergeFields = mergedfields;

widgetinfo.mergeFieldInfo = mergedfieldinfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MergeField[] mergedfields = new MergeField[4];
mergedfields[0] = new MergeField();
mergedfields[1] = new MergeField();
mergedfields[2] = new MergeField();
mergedfields[3] = new MergeField();
mergedfields[0].fieldName = "name";
mergedfields[0].defaultValue = "Your value";
mergedfields[1].fieldName = "your fildname";
mergedfields[1].defaultValue = "Your value";
mergedfields[2].fieldName = "your fildname";
mergedfields[2].defaultValue = "Your value";
mergedfields[3].fieldName = "your fildname";
mergedfields[3].defaultValue = "Your value";
```

I tried with above code and its working smoothly..